# Multiple proxy setting in maven

Tags: maven

I'm new to Maven and I have a query. Is it possible to configure multiple proxies in maven? If so how? Please reply back with example.

I tried finding out it by giving multiple proxies in my local workspace but it didn't work. Nowhere I see the correct explanation. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Maven site https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

If you would like to add multiple proxies then you need to add all proxy under  tag. I was able to add multiple proxies and it worked.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
 ...
 <proxies>
   <proxy>
    <id>myproxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
     <protocol>http</protocol>
     <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
     <port>8080</port>
    <username>proxyuser</username>
     <password>somepassword</password>
     <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
   <proxy>
    <id>myproxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
     <protocol>http</protocol>
     <host>proxy.example.com</host>
     <port>8080</port>
    <username>proxyuser</username>
     <password>somepassword</password>
     <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
 </proxies>
  ...
</settings>
```

Comment: According to the documentation you referenced, there can only be one active proxy. Doesn't Maven complain about it? Which proxy did it use?

Comment: I have Dynamic proxies, so everyday for Maven Build I had to change host name. After doing lot of research, I started using multiple proxies on settings.xml and it worked, above is example how you can set up. Maven allows multiple proxies. Check the tag name its <proxies> and subchild is  <proxy> , that's pretty much give away that you can add as many proxies you have. Since I have added all my proxies in settings.xml, I don't have to change proxy daily and all build working fine.  Please give a try, if it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: If you use multiple proxies, which proxy would maven pick ?